# Not enough information to infer type variable E

Tags: kotlin

this error appear in kotlin

Not enough information to infer type variable E
Classifier 'Person' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

```
    Realm.init(this)
    val config=RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .name("person.realm").build()
    val realm=Realm.getInstance(config)
    realm.beginTransaction()

    val person=realm.createObject(Person,1)
    person.name="محمود حسينى"
    person.age=33
    person.job="مهندس"
```

Comment: What is `createObject()`? What type is its first parameter? (Whatever it is, a bare classname is unlikely to be acceptable.)

Comment: Creation of new table in realm database